# Creating a post service along with POST parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I have an API that is like below : 
url: http://test.com/api/

This api has the following post parameters:
`token: mytoken`
`content: project`
`format: json`
`returnFormat: json`

I am trying to write a service to retrive the data. The service that I wrote is :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class RedCapTestService {
    parameters: Object = {
        'token': 'mytoken',
        'content': 'project',
        'format': 'json',
        'returnFormat': 'json'
    };
    baseUrl = 'https://test.com/api/';

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

getProjectInfo() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, this.parameters).map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}

}
```

I have a test component that I test the service. 
in the `test.component.ts`

```
export class RedcapTestProjectInfoComponent implements OnInit {
project: any = {};

 constructor(private redcapService: RedCapTestService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getProjectInfo();
}

getProjectInfo() {
  this.redcapService.getProjectInfo().subscribe(project => {
    this.project = project;
  }, error => {
    console.log('error occured');
  });
}

}
```

And here is my html teamplate:

```
<h1>Project info</h1>

<p>Project ID: {{ project.project_id }} </p>
<p>Project Title: {{ project.project_title }} </p>
```

This gives me no error but no data.
The error is :
`OPTIONS https://test.com/api/ 501 (Not Implemented)`
`Failed to load https://test.com/api/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501.`

How can I use this API along with those POST parameters in order to get the data.

PS: I am able to retrieve those data via postman.

Comment: If you're trying to send them as the POST body, then they need to be part of an Object...

Comment: use httpClient, not deprecated Http

Comment: Just updated the post. Added object in the post parameter, and this is angular 2 so Http module can work.

Comment: What is the response received? And what are the headers that you are sending?

Comment: response 200OK. but no data. I was able to get those data from PostMan.No heads. Just POST parameters.

Comment: Where and how do you use the service? Can you add a snippet of the code where the  service is called.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After  some research, I found out that in my case, I should send those parameters in `FormData()` as below:

```
getProjectInfo() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('token', 'mytoken');
    formData.append('content', 'project');
    formData.append('format', 'json');
    formData.append('returnFormat', 'json');
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, formData).map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If you use `HttpClient`, then simply just remove the `map` operator.